# Can a mock be reused for multiple expected calls with different return values in Hippo Mocks?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mocking, hippomocks

I'm using Hippo Mocks to great success, but I have a situation that I can't quite figure out how to set up properly. The code under test looks sorta like this:

```
auto firstName = record.at("firstName").getValue();
auto lastName = record.at("lastName").getValue();
```

Where `IRecord::at()` returns a `IColumn&`, which has a pure virtual `getValue()` method. I'm trying to test my code with mocked versions of `Irecord` and `IColumn`:

```
auto mockRec = mocks.InterfaceMock<IRecord>();
auto mockCol = mocks.InterfaceMock<IColumn>();
```

I can set up the expectations for `firstName` just fine:

```
mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("firstName").Return(std::ref(*mockCol));
mocks.OnCall(mockCol, IColumn::getValue).Return(std::string("John")));
```

But I would like to reuse the `IColumn` mock for the next expectation for `lastName`.

```
mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("lastName").Return(std::ref(*mockCol));
mocks.OnCall(mockCol, IColumn::getValue).Return(std::string("Doe")));
```

But when I run this, Hippo Mocks returns "John" for both `getValue()` calls.

Following along with the [tutorial](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/hippomocks/wiki/Tutorial_3_0), I tried to restrict the order of "firstName" and "lastName" calls:

```
auto& firstCall = mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("firstName").Return(std::ref(*mockCol));
mocks.OnCall(mockCol, IColumn::getValue).After(firstCall).Return(std::string("John")));

auto& lastCall = mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("lastName").Return(std::ref(*mockCol));
mocks.OnCall(mockCol, IColumn::getValue).After(lastCall).Return(std::string("Doe")));
```

But I still get "John" for both `getValue()` calls.

**Q:** Is it possible to reuse the `IColumn` interface and tell Hippo Mocks to return different values with each `getValue()` call like I need, or am I stuck creating a separate `IColumn` mock for each parameter? Note: My actual implementation will have more than two parameters, so reusing the `IColumn` mock reduces a lot of setup for each unit test.

Comment: To be quite honest, how should it know which answer you're expecting? In both cases you tell it that you want to return "John" for the next 0..N calls... One option is to make the getValue an ExpectCall with .After(the at call). That way it can only be called once and will only be allowed when the OnCall for at has been done at least once.

Comment: @dascandy "how should it know which answer you're expecting?" Because I used the `.After()` in an attempt say "first return string A, next time it's called return string B, etc". That didn't seem to work. Making it an `ExpectCall` is also a problem because I was trying to put this in a general `setupMocks()` for a set of unit tests, where some tests aren't required to call `getValue()`. Thanks for the help though (I know you're HippoMocks author).

Comment: Hm... makes sense to think of it like that. After only specifies a precondition though; it is not an immediate order requirement. OnCall also specifies that it is valid for the next N calls, not just one call. I know that Thomas added a more configurable limit specification to it but I'm not sure how to use it and I don't see a test for it. That should allow you to do what you want though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem in your case is, but when I run the following code with the [version form the git repoitory](https://github.com/dascandy/hippomocks)

```
struct IColumn {
    virtual std::string getValue() = 0;
}; 

struct IRecord {
    virtual IColumn& at( std::string ) = 0;
};

void main()
{
    MockRepository mocks;

    auto mockRec = mocks.Mock<IRecord>();
    auto mockCol = mocks.Mock<IColumn>();

    auto& firstCall = mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("firstName").Return(std::ref(*mockCol));
    mocks.OnCall(mockCol, IColumn::getValue).After(firstCall).Return(std::string("John"));

    auto& lastCall = mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("lastName").Return(std::ref(*mockCol));
    mocks.OnCall(mockCol, IColumn::getValue).After(lastCall).Return(std::string("Doe"));

    std::cout << mockRec->at("firstName").getValue() << " " 
              << mockRec->at("lastName").getValue() << "\n";
}
```

I get the correct output.

```
John Doe
```

I find that I almost always use

```
mocks.autoExpect = false;
```

but in this case it doesn't make any difference.

**Edit:**

If you require more flexibility, you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<IColumn*> cols;

cols.push_back( mocks.Mock<IColumn>() );
cols.push_back( mocks.Mock<IColumn>() );

mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("firstName")
     .Return(std::ref(*cols[0]));
mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at).With("lastName")
     .Return(std::ref(*cols[1]));

mocks.OnCall(cols[0], IColumn::getValue)
     .Return(std::string("John"));
mocks.OnCall(cols[1], IColumn::getValue)
     .Return(std::string("Doe"));
```

which will work in any order of the calls. Alternatively you can also use `Do`

```
std::map<std::string, IColumn*> map;

map["firstName"] = mocks.Mock<IColumn>();
map["lastName"] = mocks.Mock<IColumn>();

mocks.OnCall(mockRec, IRecord::at)
     .Do( [&map]( std::string& key){ return std::ref(*map[key]); } );

mocks.OnCall(map["firstName"], IColumn::getValue)
     .Return(std::string("John"));
mocks.OnCall(map["lastName"], IColumn::getValue)
     .Return(std::string("Doe"));
```

Comment: I realized yesterday that I was using the version from SVN and not Git which apparently isn't as up-to-date. I haven't had a chance to retry this; I'll update when I try on the latest version.

Comment: wow, that's an awesome solution; definitely flexible! I like the `Do` version the best because it'll reduce redundant expectation lines. I wouldn't have thought of doing it that way. Thanks!

Comment: the autoExpect is to give a default order, which will make your test fail earlier. Disabling it is the correct way of using mocks, but I expect most to have underspecified order then, which will lead to odd matching order as well (as you may match another call first). It's the safe and typically wrong choice... but it's safe.